# php get character from html entity

Tags: php, html-entities

I would like to retrieve the characters is string like :

```
&#101;&#97;.&#105;c&#101;f&#105;&#101;ld&#64;
```

with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) maybe:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&#101;&#97;.&#105;c&#101;f&#105;&#101;ld&#64;');
```

> ea.icefield@

Comment: I do that, but why in my project appears normal in the view and when export this data or view the source it still as html entity

Comment: I have no idea what that means.